# Is there a way to build my own UI with charts using Kinetica API?

Tags: visualization, kinetica

I am looking at Kinetica. It seems to be an awesome tool. I would like to know, instead of using the workbench, I want to build my own UI but use the Kinetica API to show the charts for the data that I obtain after executing an SQL statement.
Simply put, I m looking to build a chatbot with user asking questions, the bot returns data and also shows options to visualize just like it does in the workbench. Then the bot can show the charts.

But the chatbot is something I would like to build on my own and not using the workbench provided by Kinetica.

Any ideas? I hope the question is clear.